# Python Numerology Program returning false results (working with lists)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, character

I am supposed to write a program that takes a person's whole name and returns the name's numerical value. The numerical value is found by the values of the letters in the name (with a=1, b=2...z=26).

This is what I have so far:

```
 def main ():

    name = input("What is the whole name? ").lower()    #get name, make all lowercase

    alph = [" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]      #list of characters

    total = 0                                   #apply value for each character in name
    for ch in name:
        total = ord(ch) + total - 96            

    print("The numerical value of the name is \n", total)   #print the result

main()
```

For some reason my program works with some of the names I input (such as dani = 28), but other names (notably longer ones) are not returning correct answers. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the whole homework problem for reference:

Numerologists claim to be able to determine a person's character traits based on the "numeric value" of a name. The value of a name is determined by summing up the values of the letters of the name where 'a' is 1, 'b' is 2, 'c' 3 etc., up to 'z' being 26. For example, the name "Zelle" would have the value 26+5+12+12+5=60. Write a program that calculates the numeric value of a single name provided as input.

Expand your solution to the previous problem to allow the calculation of a complete name such as "Jackson Thomas Mills." The total value is just the sum of the numeric values of all the names.

Comment: If someone have to read "the whole homework problem" your question is not clear enough {downvote}, and if the question is clear then the latter part is unnecessary.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Have you tried to debug your program?

Comment: Do you understand your code (especially the `ord(ch) + total - 96` part) or you're just copy-and-paste your professor's code? Learn more about ASCII please.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing I noticed is that that your program doesnt account for spaces in names. The -96 part is important, the code is taking the letters, converting them to Unicode, then subtracting that from 96. The space also has a Unicode value, but when you subtract 96 from that, the value comes out negative, which in turn skews the total. So you need to figure out how to surpass the space in the program.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a print total to the loop, you would learn you have to ignore non-alphabetical characters.